# How can i fetch the value from database in a simple module?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I'm working in drupal 7 and I have tried all help but not able to fetch the value from database.

```
    function myModule_load($node){

    $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {uc_auction_bids} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => 258,)); 
$record = $result->fetch(); 

    // print the fields/values of $record 
print('<pre>'); print_r($record); print('</pre>');
```

and also

```
    function myModule_block_view($delta) {    
       if (($node = menu_get_object()) && ($node->type === 'product')) {
        $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {uc_auction_bids} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => $node->nid));
        $records = $results->fetchAllAssoc('bid');

        $content = ... // Format records here...

        return array(
          'subject' => t('Bids'),
          'content' => $content
        );   } }
```

I want to fetch the value in module and in the page, but not at the top of the drupal header

Comment: Did you try $result->execute() and then print_r ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view
 */
function MY_MODULE_block_view($delta = '') {

  if (($node = menu_get_object()) && ($node->type == 'product')) {      
    $query = db_select('uc_auction_bids', 'bids');
    $query->fields('bids');
    $query->condition('nid', $node->nid);
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('bid');

    // Debug
    drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($result,1).'</pre>');

    $content = ''; // Format records here...

    return array(
      'subject' => t('Bids'),
      'content' => $content
    );   
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch values from database: you can try this.

```
   $query = db_select('uc_auction_bids', 'u');
   $query->fields('u', array('field1', 'field2')); // and other fields required
   $query->condition('nid', $nid_value, '=');
   $result = $query->execute();
   foreach ($result as $record) {

    //USE $record->field1;
    //USE $record->field2; 
    // and so on

    }
```

Comment: hello sir but i m creating a module and i want to call this query in a function

Comment: you can put this inside a function. I gave only quering part.